# how to delete .class file in a nested jar file (A .jar contains B.jar (inside B.jar there is .class file)

Tags: linux, jar

Could you please help command in Linux how to delete the .class file from inside a nested jar file

EX: A Jar Contains B.Jar (in side B.jar contains test.class) file

Now in above scenario i wanted to delete the test.class file from B.jar which is inside A.Jar .

Can you please help with linux command to perform this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this related to programming?

Comment: I too wish for this as a workaround for urgent security issues involving some unused Jndi functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Example: /scanfix2.sh JndiLookup

if [ $# -lt 1 ] ; then
  exit 1
fi
for i in `find . | grep -iE "(\.jar$|\.war$)"`;
do
        c=`jar -tf $i | grep -i "\.jar" | wc -l`
        if [ $c -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "Scanning $i"
                b=`basename $i`
                f=`pwd`
                rm -rf /tmp/$b
                mkdir /tmp/$b
                cp $i $i.bck
                cp $i /tmp/$b/$b
                cd /tmp/$b
                jar -xf $b
                rm $b
                rm -rf scanfix_$b.txt
                for j in `find .|grep -i /$1.class`;
                do
                        mv $j $j.bck
                        echo Fixed $i $j >> scanfix_$b.txt
                done
                /scanfix2.sh $1 $i >> scanfix_$b.txt
                cc=`cat scanfix_$b.txt|grep Fixed|wc -l`
                if [ $cc -gt 0 ]; then
                        jar cf $b .
                        echo Nested $b [$cc fixes]
                        cat scanfix_$b.txt
                        cd $f
                        cp /tmp/$b/$b .

                else
                        cd $f
                        rm $i.bck
                fi
        else
                echo "Checking $2$i"
                for j in `jar -tf $i|grep -i /$1.class`;
                do
                        cp $i $i.bck
                        zip -q -d $i $j
                        echo Fixed $i $j
                done
        fi
done
```